# Migration PHP/Apache workspace from Cloud9 to AWS

Tags: apache, cloud9, aws-cloud9

Not sure this is the right place, if not, please be kind.

I recently migrated a PHP/Apache workspace from Cloud9 to AWS Cloud9.  I followed the migration step, everything was fine. I have a new AWS Cloud9 workspace with all my files ... but I can't launch the server.

Previously, I clicked on Run and the Apache server started. Now, nothing happens. I wonder if I have any configuration to perform ?

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to manually configure Apache to run on ports 8080, 8081 and 8082.

This page details how to run Apache on AWS EC2 Cloud9 server (ports configuration, root directory and enabling htaccess): [How to configure and run Apache server on AWS EC2 Cloud9?](https://www.lucidar.me/en/aws-cloud9/how-to-run-apache-on-aws-ec2-cloud9-server/)